# How to install multiple ruby gems at once?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

Is is possible to install more than one gem at the same time with only one command?

Answer (score 24):

The `gem install` command accepts many parameters, so you can `gem install nokogiri bundler` in one shot, for instance.

As others said, [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) and [RVM](https://rvm.io/) makes everything connected to managing gems, versions and dependencies a real pleasure.

Comment: Hey i-blis I need to install all gems in a directory (along with dependency gems, and yes I have all dependence gems inside one directory) without using RVM or any other gem. How to do this?

Comment: Interestingly, `gem install` makes separate requests for each gem. Bundler’s `bundle install` makes a single request. Bundler is more performant because of this.

Answer (score 4):

You can put them in a `Gemfile` and use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) (`bundle install`).

Alternatively, you could list the commands in a file:

```
gem install pg
gem install sqlite3
```

and use something like `cat <filename> | xargs sudo` to execute them.

**Consider using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to manage your gems into gemsets rather than installing them globally with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You can using bundler: http://gembundler.com/