# What is the syntax for `gem install` multiple gems, specifying versions for each one?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How can I use `gem install` to install multiple gems at the same time, while also specifying the versions I want?

Example:

```
gem install akami -v  1.2.0 --ignore-dependencies
gem install atomic -v  1.1.14 --ignore-dependencies
gem install aws-s3 -v 0.6.2 --ignore-dependencies
gem install backports -v  3.3.0 --ignore-dependencies
gem install brendanlim-sms-fu -v 1.0.0 --ignore-dependencies
gem install builder -v  3.1.3 --ignore-dependencies
gem install capistrano -v  2.9.0 --ignore-dependencies
```

How could I instruct `gem install` to execute that in one line?

---

The accepted answer do answer the question. But the final approach I took was to use bundler 1.0.22, which is compatible with ruby 1.8.6.

Comment: You could just put these lines in a bash script and run it? But if your project allows for it, I'd highly recommend using bundler to manage gem dependencies

Comment: The bash script approach is what I am doing right now. But a single gem install will be much faster. No, we can't use Bundler in this project (ruby 1.8.6)

Comment: you probably could.... just a really old version of bundler. v1.1 introduced the 1.8.7 requirement. Alternatively, update your app to a ruby version that isn't years past end of life.

Comment: Boy would I love to do that :) I will see if I can install an old version of bundler. We have an immense app, so upgrading it to a modern is out of scope. We are taking the services approach, where we extract chunks into new apps.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498810/how-to-install-multiple-ruby-gems-at-once.

Comment: @saurabh Not a duplicate, because this questions have the constraint of specifying the versions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since Rubygems 2.0 you can specify a version for multiple package installations like this:

```
$ gem install akami:1.2.0 atomic:1.1.14 aws-s3:0.6.2 backports:3.3.0 \
brendanlim-sms-fu:1.0.0 builder:3.1.3 capistrano:2.9.0 \
--ignore-dependencies
```

Comment: this does not work with Ruby 1.9.3, gem 1.8.11 Only with Ruby 2 ?

Comment: @geekQ Yes, this feature was introduced with Rubygems 2.0, answer updated.

Comment: It's more interesting how to define version range for each one. For example I want to install `bundler -v '>= 1.3.0, < 2.0'` and `net-ssh -v '>= 2.9.2, < 5.0'` as one command. Is there right way for it?